# my child router can't go back to another parent router in Angular2(rc3)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

the route doesn't work when i enter into a parent route which has a sub-routing from a sub-routing

main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http'
import {SeedApp} from './app/seed-app';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from './app/main.routes';

bootstrap(SeedApp, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

main.routes.ts:

```
import...//ignore
export const MainRoutes:RouterConfig=[
{path: 'static/setting', component: Setting,children:[
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'network', terminal: true},
    {path: 'network', component: SettingNetwork},
    {path: 'date', component: SettingTimeAndDate},
    {path: 'video', component: SettingVideo}
]},
{path: 'static/deployment', component: Deployment},
{path: 'static/real_time_results', component: RealTimeResults},
{path: 'static/whitelists', component: WhiteLists,children:[
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'recognition', terminal: true},
    {path: 'recognition', component: Recognition},
    {path: 'white', component: White},
    {path: 'black', component: Black }
]},
{path: 'static/input_output', component: InputOutput},
{path: 'static/about', component: About},
{path: 'static/data', component: Data},
{path: 'static/upgrade_reset', component: UpgradeReset,children:[
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'upgrade', terminal: true},
    {path: 'upgrade', component: Upgrade},
    {path: 'reset', component: Reset}
]},
{path: 'static/history', component: History}
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS=[
provideRouter(MainRoutes)
];
```

seed-app.ts:

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router,RouterLink,Route,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {Router,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import ...//ignore

@Component({
selector: 'seed-app',
template:require('./seed-app.html'),
styles:[require('./seed-app.css').toString()],
directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
providers: [LogService]
})

export class SeedApp implements OnInit {
private service:LogService;
private passwordResult = '';
private old_psd:string;
private psd:string;
private new_psd:string;
private menus=[
    {name:'实时结果',address:'/static/real_time_results'},
    {name:'部署设置',address:'/static/deployment'},
    {name:'白名单',address:'/static/whitelists/recognition'},
    {name:'输入输出',address:'/static/input_output'},
    {name:'数据同步',address:'/static/data'},
    {name:'历史记录',address:'/static/history'},
    {name:'设置',address:'/static/setting/network'},
    {name:'升级&重置',address:'/static/upgrade_reset/upgrade'},
    {name:'关于',address:'/static/about'}
];

constructor(private http:Http, public router:Router) {
    this.service = new LogService(http);
}
}
```

seed-app.html:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li *ngFor="let menu of menus" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" >
                    <a class="row nav-list" [routerLink]="[menu.address]">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <span class="menu-text">{{menu.name}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

setting.html:(one of the children routes,others the same to )

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified settings-nav">
    <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" ><a [routerLink]="['date']">日期和时间</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['network']">网络</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['video']">视频</a></li>
</ul>
```

upgrade-reset.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified upgrade-reset-nav">
    <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['upgrade']">升级</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"  [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['reset']">重置</a></li>
</ul>
```

whitelists.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified settings-nav" role="pilllist">
    <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['recognition']">识别设置</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['white']">白名单</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['black']">黑名单</a></li>
</ul>
```

whitelists.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {Recognition} from './whitelists-recognition';
import {White} from './whitelists-white';
import {Black} from './whitelists-black';

@Component({
    selector: 'whitelists',
    template:require('./whitelists.html'),
    styles:[require('./whitelists.css').toString()],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class WhiteLists {

    constructor(public router:Router) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What `routerLink` doesn't work? In which component is the `routerLink` that doesn't work?

Comment: `/static/setting/network ` to `/static/upgrade_reset/upgrade`;or `/static/setting/network ` to `/static/whitelists/recognition`

Comment: I don't see that `routerLink` in your code.

Comment: I don't get it. The `routerLink`s you added are to other child routes. I still can't find the `routerLinks` for the routes you mentioned in the comment above (the ones that don't work).